# How do i execute a properties file from a shell script

Tags: linux, sonarqube

i have written a sonar-project.properties
file for sonar and now i want to execute this file from a shell script, how do i call a properties file from a shell script please could some someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a Sonar analysis, then you have to [install the Sonar Runner](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Sonar+Runner) and then launch

```
sonar-runner
```

in the folder where you put your "sonar-project.properties" file.

Everything is perfectly explained in [the documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Sonar+Runner).

Comment: is sonar runner different from sonar instalation because i have installed sonar, do i need to install sonar runner seperately?

Comment: @user1720124 Yes. The Sonar runner is the client-side part of Sonar that performs the source code analysis on your local code. Once this is done results are uploaded to the Sonar server. Other types of Sonar client are the Sonar ANT task and Sonar Maven plugin.